# PHP - retrieve data from an array

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following array i obtain after running a `var_dump($response)`.

```
array (size=2)
  'count' => int 3
  'data' => 
    array (size=3)
       0 => array (size=38)
          'ref' => string '24750.0.2530' (length=12)
       1 => array (size=38)
          'ref' => string '24450.0.2530' (length=12)
```

i would like to display the 'ref' from the above array.tried running a `foreach` as below but i get a notice

> Trying to get property of non-object

```
foreach($response as $object)
{
    var_dump($object->ref);
}
```

Comment: Sir, please remove the personal or perhaps even confidential information from your post. You shouldn't post other people's email addresses in your code examples.

Comment: Downvoters on here become like kids enjoying to hit the elevator button labelled with a downward arrow. Why don't you people start commenting on the reasons for your downvotes, so that the community can actually adapt and better itself?

Comment: well said Lak'esh..seems some people enjoy hitting the down arrow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($response['data'] as $data) {
    var_dump($data['ref']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it isn't an object. It is an array of arrays. Try:

```
foreach ($response['data'] as $data) {
    var_dump($data['ref']);
}
```